# Rails model with 2 foreign keys but only one gets saved when submitting form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-key-relationship, nested-form-for

I'm trying to save a form_for with nested resources that inputs data into a model that belongs to 2 other models and has 2 foreign keys: User_id and listing_id.

The problem is that only the user_id gets saved despite the fact that both ids are being created ,as shown in the console, and the listing_id is passed with the correct value.

I might be missing something obvious but i'm fairly new to Rails. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Application model:

```
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :listing
```

Listing model:

```
    has_many :applications
```

User model

```
    has_many :applications
```

Controller:

```
    class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! 


    def index

    end

    def update
      @application = current_user.applications.create  
    end


    def new 
      @application = Application.new
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])

    end

    def create
      @application =     current_user.applications.create(application_params)
      redirect_to listing_applications_path
    end

    def your_applications
      @apps = current_user.applications

    end

    private
      def application_params
        params.require(:application).permit(:listing_id, :st_address, :unit, :city, :state, :move_in,:first_name, :last_name, :phone_numer, :pets, :current_address, :previous_landlord_name, :previous_landlord_phone, :company, :company_address, :company_phone, :is_40X, :annual_income)
      end
  end
```

View:

```
      <%= form_for [:listing, @application] do |f| %>
```

routes.rb

```
    resources :listings do
      resources :applications
    end
```

This is what I get in the controller- https://i.stack.imgur.com/e52T0.png.  The listing_id is passed already as a parameter but gets lost when saving the form.

> Processing by ApplicationsController#new as HTML
>   Parameters: {"listing_id"=>"13"}
>
> Processing by ApplicationsController#create as HTML
>   Parameters: {........, "listing_id"=>"13"}
>
> User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
>      (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "applications" (.......) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [....., ["user_id", 11], ["created_at", ....], ["updated_at", ....]]
>
> Listing Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]

It seems like the listing_id is being passed but not inserted. Why is that?

Comment: How are you passing listing_id to the create action? What does the complete form look like?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but it seems like the listing_id is passed from the url but not inserted based on the message in the console. I added the console messages above. I also included this line in the "new" action:  @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id]) but still I have the same problem.

Comment: I found a solution which is to create a hidden field in the view that will be pre populated with the listing_id. In that case it works if I add the following to the view: <%= f.text_field :listing_id, value: params[:listing_id], class: "form-control hidden"%>. But it seems not elegant and I wish I can find a better solution. I still don't understand why the listing_id is not saved without adding that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to add a hidden field in the view that will be pre populated with the listing_id.

It works if this is added to to the view:

```
    <%= f.text_field :listing_id, value: params[:listing_id], class: "form-control hidden"%>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'new' action shouldn't be creating anything.  It should be:

@application = Application.new

And your "update" action should not be creating a new record but updating the record that was just edited. So that would become:

```
@application = Application.find(params[:id])
@application.update_attributes(application_params)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the same result. The listing_id is not saving.